# Initialize a blockchain based on PoS

Tags: blockchain, proof-of-stake, staking

How a blockchain based on PoS could be initialized if nobody has the coins to become a Validator?

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain of this answer, so please correct me if wrong.

In the case of Ethereum, the blockchain starts at block 0, which is the genesis block, which is described in the file (usualy) called `genesis.json`.

In this file, you can determine a number of factors for the blockchain, including addresses and their starting balance.

As a consequence, the address(es) to which you gave ether at the beginning would be able to create blocks.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it means that validators are limited to the addresses from the genesis block?

Comment: @Amo not if other addresses get ether (in a way or another) later on.